# Slow speed Search Query WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, performance

I have this query when I decrease filters its become fast but as I increase filters its become too slow, Please I need to make it fast with all these filters.
As my details are clears but I am writing some lines because its does not allow me to post my Question

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'property', 'posts_per_page' => 1,'order' => 'asc', 
            'meta_query'    => array(
                            'relation'      => 'AND',
                                  array(
                                     'key'      => 'facilityname',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['keyword'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'city',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['city'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'facilitytype',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['facilitytype'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'hospitaltype',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['hospitaltype'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'state',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['state'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                     
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'idn',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['idn'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                       array(
                                     'key'      => 'gpoaffiliations',
                                     'value'        => $_GET['gpoaffiliations'],
                                     'compare'  => 'LIKE'
                                      ),
                                        array(
                                     'key'      => 'bedcounttotal',
                                     'value'        =>  array($_GET['min-bedcounttotal'], $_GET['max-bedcounttotal']),
                                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                      ),
                                        array(
                                     'key'      => 'zipcode',
                                     'value'        =>  array($_GET['minzipcode'], $_GET['maxzipcode']),
                                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                      ),
                                        array(
                                     'key'      => 'operatingroomcount',
                                     'value'        =>  array($_GET['minoperatingroomcount'], $_GET['maxoperatingroomcount']),
                                      'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                      'type' => 'NUMERIC'
                                      ),
                                     
                                     
                                      
                             )
          );
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see a scenario where that many `LIKE` comparisons in one query could ever be fast. Depending on the size of the dataset you are searching you might want to offer the user a predefined set of options for most of those inputs and then use an = comparison instead of LIKE.

Comment: Thanks for comment so what should I used instead of "LIKE" ?

Comment: Instead of `LIKE`, just use `=`. I think `state`, `hospitaltype` and `facilitytype` can definitely be switched to that, unless you are letting people search for `isconsi` or something. You can also get the actual SQL query from `$wp_query` and try to [manually optimize it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html) or the tables holding the data

Comment: Please provide (1) the generated SQL, and (2) SHOW CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Its searching about 21k Posts let me edit my question

Comment: @RickJames I have share my loop below

Comment: @FunkDoc = is not working its finding nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, I am sharing it here for other may have same problem Like me

```
$meta_query = array();
    $args = array();
    $args = array('posts_per_page' => -1,);
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'facilityname',
        'value' => $_GET['keyword'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'city',
        'value' => $_GET['city'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'facilitytype',
        'value' => $_GET['facilitytype'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'hospitaltype',
        'value' => $_GET['hospitaltype'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'state',
        'value' => $_GET['state'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'idn',
        'value' => $_GET['idn'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'gpoaffiliations',
        'value' => $_GET['gpoaffiliations'],
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'bedcounttotal',
        'value'     =>  array($_GET['min-bedcounttotal'], $_GET['max-bedcounttotal']),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'zipcode',
        'value'     =>  array($_GET['minzipcode'], $_GET['maxzipcode']),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
    $meta_query[] = array(
        'key' => 'operatingroomcount',
        'value'     =>  array($_GET['minoperatingroomcount'], $_GET['maxoperatingroomcount']),
        'compare'   => 'BETWEEN',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC'
    );
    //if there is more than one meta query 'or' them
    if(count($meta_query) > 1) {
        $meta_query['relation'] = 'AND';
    }
    
    // The Query
    $args['post_type'] = "property";
    $args['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
```